# Partition UUID was changed automatically

Tags: partitioning, grub2, 22.04, postgresql, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 running on AWS cloud with the following specifications:

**Operating System**: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
**AMI ID**: ami-07651f0c4c315a529
**AMI Name**: ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-jammy-22.04-amd64-server-20220912
**Instance Type**: t3a.medium

We have Postgresql 14 installed on it with TimescaleDB extension. Sometimes the system will be rebooted due to OOM killer, but it will fail to reboot due to error message: PARTUUID does not exist.

[image: Screenshot of the error message]

The first time when this happened, we noticed it was because the PARTUUID is different from what is listed using the command:

```
$ blkid
```

We thought it was an one-off thing, we detached the EBS volume and attached it to a rescue EC2, mounted it, edited the grub.cfg and changed the PARTUUID to the correct one. However, it happens once in a while. We have raised this issue to AWS support but they said update and patching from AWS shouldn't affect the PARTUUID. So I am at a dead end here, does anyone have any idea how to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Does the filesystem UUID change? If not, use that instead

Comment: you mean in the grub.cfg file or from the command blkid? actually, both UUID and PARTUUID don't change from command blkid, it is the PARTUUID in grub.cfg that was changed automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Did you get a resolution to this? I've got exactly the same problem with mysterious grub.cfg changes that have happened twice now. Exactly the same PARTUUID as in your screenshot as well.

I only had them start occurring after the last time I shrunk the single EC2 volume on my instance (beginning of November) so had put it down to that in some way, but given it's not consistent when I reboot, and the server had started up in the first place, I couldn't put definitely attribute it to that (and had shrunk the single volume previously without this issue).

I fix it by creating an identical EC2 instance with a single root volume (instance B), detaching the root volume from the B instance and attaching to be the root volume on the original EC2 instance (instance A) with the real root volume for instance A detached and reattached & mounted as an additional volume. This will then boot and start up all its processes properly (both instance A and B volumes have all the same UUID/PARTUUID/labels due to how AWS is creating them), if not then try again etc. Then I take the working root volume grub.cfg (i.e. what came over from instance B) and replace the instance A one which is mounted with it. Then stop instance A, detach both volumes, put the original instance A volume back as the root volume and reboot. All should be fine now and terminate instance B and its volume.
I've just done this today, yet again, and am hoping it lasts more than a month this time round.

Comment: I think I've solved it, but not what caused it to start happening.

Comment: /etc/default/grub.d/40-force-partuuid.cfg contains a variable forcing the erroneous PARTUUID to be used when generating the grub.cfg. I commented out that variable, moved the grub.cfg out the way and did a sudo update-grub and all is good after a reboot. Kernel updates regenerate the grub.cfg which is why, sporadically, a reboot failed as the hardcoded PARTUUID was coming from that file. Quite where this config file came from I've no idea though... so it might come back at some point?

Answer (score 1):

Did you resize/expand your root disk/filesystem?  In my case, I think that is what changed the value of PARTUUID on the disk.